# How do I determine what database WSUS on my Windows Server 2012 is using?

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012, wsus

I installed WSUS on a fresh installation of Windows Server 2012 (I assume this is WSUS 4 as it is bundled with Server 2012 with no option to download it anywhere online)

I did not install any additional database services apart from whatever WSUS did on its own.

Im now trying to connect to the database instance so that I can run maintenance scripts [as per this WSUS 3 article](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/6f8cde49-5c52-4abd-9820-f1d270ddea61) but am failing!

Im sure it would help as a starter if I could identify what database service is being used.

Comment: In 2012 it's actually WSUS 6 (don't ask.)  Unless you specify a SQL server and instance WSUS will default to installing the Windows Internal Database feature

Comment: 6 yes, although it is technically equivalent to the standalone WSUS 3. Only change is the support for WID 2012.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Windows Internal Database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Internal_Database)

"Windows Internal Database (codenamed WYukon, sometimes referred to as SQL Server Embedded Edition) is a variant of SQL Server Express 2005-2012 or that is included with Windows Server 2008 (SQL 2005), Windows Server 2008 R2 (SQL 2005) and Windows Server 2012 (SQL 2012)."

That Wikipedia article also says:

> "SQL Server Management Studio Express can be used to connect to an
>   instance of Windows Internal Database using
>   `\\.\pipe\MSSQL$MICROSOFT##SSEE\sql\query` (for 2003-2008) or
>   `\\.\pipe\MICROSOFT##WID\tsql\query` (for 2012) as instance name. But this
>   will only work locally, as Remote Connections cannot be enabled for
>   this edition of SQL Server. Also note that "Windows Authentication"
>   should be used (as opposed to SQL Server Authentication), and
>   administrators seem to have the best results of authenticating
>   successfully when logged on using the same administrative account that
>   was created when Windows was installed."

Comment: Please mind the Tsql part! I took me about 30 minutes of frustration before I noticed the extra "T". I was able to use any account with local admin-rights on the server.

Comment: Serverfault FTW :) Nice to find guys who are knowledgeable about their subject! Can you tell me - is the db maintenance (re-indexing) script still required to be run monthly for WSUS 6?